attempt to compare Instance <= number Roblox Studio
Trying to make a basic buy system with a sword, I have 2 IntValues, one for the price of the object and another for the currency of the player. Idk what happens but the code doesn't work.
Code of the buy system:
local lp = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local ls = lp.leaderstats
local backpack = lp.Backpack
local rp = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local price = script.Parent.Price

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if ls.Money.Value >= price or ls.Money.Value == price then
        local tool = rp.Tools.ClassicSword:Clone()
        tool.Parent = backpack
        ls.Money.Value = ls.Money.Value-price
        print("Player has enough money to purchase tool, player currency now is"..ls.Money.Value)
    else return end
end)


If I'm correct this is a LocalScript. The problem is the LocalPlayer has no network ownership over the leaderstats value Money so when the LocalPlayer tries to edit it will not replicate to the server.
You should make the buy system on the server. I recommend using a RemoteEvent that fires the server and then the server will handle the purchase and clones the tool to the player's backpack.

And how I can configure a RemoteEvent to do that?

@Gamer2VR you should read into this. Remote Events and Callbacks
